# The London 2018 World Chess Championship live coverage sources

Tags: world-championship

Which TV channels are going to stream the WCC? Preferably with English commentary. (With live video from the playing board, not only the moves).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the live video footage is restricted to the official broadcast and you probably have to pay to get access to it.
The footage aside, the games will be broadcasted live on chess24 for free (even without an account) with a phenomenal team of commentators, namely, Peter Svidler, Sopiko Guramishvili, Alexander Grischuk, Anish Giri for the English commentary and there will also be separate commentaries in Spanish and German covering each round.

- Here's their dedicated page to the WCC2018: https://chess24.com/en/wcc2018
- And the featured page (including engine analysis etc): https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/carlsen-caruana-world-chess-championship-2018/1/1/1

Comment: And in case you miss the live coverage, everything is recorded and uploaded to their official youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/user/chess24media/videos so you can watch them later, and on top of that there are many fun/instructive banter blitz sessions to watch as well (by Svidler, Grischuk, Guramishvili and others). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The [Norwegian National Broadcasting](https://www.nrk.no/sport/sjakk/) (NRK) will be covering the championship, both online and on their main TV channels, with Norwegian commentary led by [IM Torstein Bae](https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=1501887). They probably won't have a *constant* camera at the board and the contestants, but it will feature front and center much of the time.

Earlier productions they have done (and thus, I would presume, this one too) have been aimed at a lower level (I would expect them to explain things like en passant, the exact limitations on castling, and the concepts of pins and discoveries, possibly several times over the course of these days, especially if any game reaches a position where it is relevant), but they still make good analyses of positions and tactics, and it's generally well produced and fun to watch.

**Edit:** I have realized since writing this that it's only available in Norway. I've been abroad myself and unable to reach it.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://www.chess.com/tv. It is a popular streaming channel.